# Ajax's data parameter not making it to the server

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Okay here's my problem.

I have an html page that has a javascript variable initialized in it.

```
<html>
   <script>
      MyVaribale = "Random Data";
   </script>

   <!-- Then I include an external js file to handle the processes in this    html file -->

   <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="/scripts/some_random_script.js"></script>

</html>
```

Now, inside that script. I used the `MyVaribale`varible in one of the ajax request there, like this :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $.ajax(
       url : '/some/random/url',
       data : { MyVariable : MyVaribale }
       etc ...
   );
});
```

So, on page load, that ajax code is executed immediately.

In the url specified above, i checked for the existence of `MyVaribale`, then flag an error that it is a required value if it doesn't exist.

Backend code like this (in Perl):

```
my $MyVariable = trim_param('MyVariable'); # trim_param() is a function that gets the passed data from ajax.

if ( $MyVariable ) { # Test if it exists
    # Display something
}
else {
   # Flag an error, which is my problem
}
```

**Now I am sure that in the html page, that variable is always populated (yes 100% sure).** But I always get flag errors that that value doesn't exist in my backend code (url above).

So question,

**Does ajax have some issue with `document.ready`, maybe it executes before the variable has finished assigning a value? Any idea why this happens? Because sometimes my ajax request is successful, sometimes it's not**

Thanks

Comment: Can you post your backend code too?

Comment: After `$(document).ready(function() {` if you add `console.log(MyVaribale)` do you see the contents of the variable in your console?

Comment: @DarrenSweeney yes. Note that this happens sometimes, but also, sometimes my ajax request is successful, so Im asking if there's a know issue with ajax and document.ready

Comment: No, there is no problem with using ajax and document.ready

Answer (score 1):

The syntax of your ajax call is not correct. Have a look [here](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) and then try this code (note the addition of `{`, `}` and `,`):

```
MyVaribale = "Random Data";

$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
       url: '/some/random/url',
       data : { myVariable : MyVaribale }
    });
});
```

Comment: The code I posted seems correct, you can try it (and edit if you want) here: http://jsfiddle.net/jf3wz8a9/

Comment: Yeah i know the code is correct. Because sometimes the ajax call is successful, sometimes it is not. which flags an error in the server.

Comment: There must be other issues causing the problem then, your code seems ok, what we can see of it

Answer (score 0):

Did not you try out some complete ajax calls? Like this.Sometimes no need to use JSON.stringify for MyVariable.

```
        $.ajax({
            url: "/some/random/url",
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: JSON.stringify(MyVaribale),
            contentType: 'application/json',
            mimeType: 'application/json'

        }).done(function(data) {

        }).fail(function(error) {

        }).always(function(){

        });
```